# node.js how can i do 530 error in smtp-server

Tags: node.js, smtp

i made a test smtp server with node.js smtp-server.
i ran the smtp server that hosts public ip address and i send email from gmail to my custom domain.

it doesn't work well. smtp server emited error.

```
S : 530 Error: authentication Required.
```

My Source

```
var SMTPServer = require('smtp-server').SMTPServer;
var SERVER_PORT = 25;
var SERVER_HOST = 'exam.example.com'; //for example
var options = {
logger: true,
size: 10*1024*1024,
authMethods: ['PLAIN'],
banner: 'My Server',
onAuth: function(auth, session, callback) {
    if(auth.username !== 'testuser' || auth.password !== 'testpass') {
        return callback(new Error('Invalid username or password'));
    }
    callback(null, {user: 'testuser'}); //where 123 is the user id or similar property
},
onConnect: function(session, callback) {
    console.log("onConnect : " + session.remoteAddress);
    console.log("session : " + session.clientHostname);
    console.log('session.hostNameAppearsAs : ' + session.hostNameAppearsAs);
    return callback(); //Accept the connection
},
onMailFrom: function(address, session, callback) {
    console.log('onMailFrom : ' + address.address);
    return callback(); //Accept the address
},
onRcptTo: function(address, session, callback) {
    console.log('onRcptTo : ' + address.address);
    return callback();//Accept the address
},
onData: function(stream, session, callback) {
    stream.pipe(process.stdout); //print message to console
    stream.on('end', function() {
        callback(null, 'message end');
    });
}
};

var server = new SMTPServer(options);
server.on('error', function(err) {
console.log('server error : ' + err);
});
server.listen(SERVER_PORT, SERVER_HOST);
```

how can i do?

Answer (score 3):

If you add `authOptional: true` to the options, it will disable mandatory authentication and your code will work just fine.